# Any name for this proposition? : Sounds reflects P.O.S. of the word

Tags: terminology, phonetics, parts-of-speech

I am using natural language processing/speech recognition techniques so that I can provide better tools to learn English pronounciation.

While research on relevant topics, I found this fact:

Certain phonemes already well-articulated to reflect its pos position. For example, for the case of the suffix `-ate`, there's a pattern like this

For Noun and adjective:
IPA(key): `[...kət]`
 **intricate, predicate, delicate**

For Verb:
IPA(key): `[...keɪt]`
 **complicate, sophisticate**

This pattern actually makes the computation process a lot faster because of this simple fact. I really glad to know this, and need to know any theoretical/academic names for this phenomenon.

Comment: This is the result of the stress shift that is used to mark POS in many words. There are other markers as well.

Comment: I see a clear question on terminology here (though I don't know any cromulent term for the phenonon described)

Comment: I see that there is a request for a term, but I can't figure out what fact is at issue. E.g. is it when the same letter sequence is pronounced differently depending on POS (narrowly) or morphosyntactic properties? Is it the fact that stress position depends on POS?